# Why My Scroll Pane is not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I am using Java Graphical Interface to show a Branch and Cut tree, but the size of the tree is large and I cannot see it completely, I decided to add scroll bar to be able to traverse easily, but it is not working. 
My code is :

```
package minemodel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class BAndBGUI {
    private int _distance;
    private JFrame _frame;
    private MyPannel _mainPannel;
    private ArrayList<NodeForTree> _node;
    public BAndBGUI(int convNumber) {
    _node=new ArrayList<NodeForTree>();
    _frame=new JFrame();
    _distance=700/convNumber;
    _mainPannel=new MyPannel();
    _frame.setVisible(true);
    _frame.setSize(1350, 700);
    _frame.setLocation(0, 0);
    _frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( _mainPannel );

    _frame.add(scrollPane);

}

public MyPannel getPanel(){
    return _mainPannel;
}

public void setNode(NodeForTree node){
    _node.add(node);
    _mainPannel.repaint();
}

public class MyPannel extends JPanel{

    /**
     * 
     * @param level the level of the current node
     * @param number number of nodes currently on that level,
     * @param Parent's locaton to draw the line.
     * @return
     */


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //  super.paintComponent(g);
        Iterator<NodeForTree> itrNode=_node.iterator();
        while (itrNode.hasNext()){
            NodeForTree node=itrNode.next();

            g.drawOval(node.getLocation()[0], node.getLocation()[1], 20, 20);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            if (node.getParent()!=null){
                g.drawString(node.toString(),node.getLocation()[0], node.getLocation()[1]+15);
                NodeForTree parrent=node.getParent();
                drawArrow(g,parrent.getLocation()[0], parrent.getLocation()[1], node.getLocation()[0], node.getLocation()[1]);
                System.out.println("parent"+parrent.getLocation()[0]+" "+parrent.getLocation()[1]+" and "+node.getLocation()[0]+" "+node.getLocation()[1]);

                //  g.drawLine(node.getLocation()[0], node.getLocation()[1],parrent.getLocation()[0], parrent.getLocation()[1]);

            }else{
                g.drawString("start",500, 15);
            }
            g.drawString(node.getObjective(),node.getLocation()[0], node.getLocation()[1]);
        }
    }

    public void drawArrow (Graphics g1, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();

        double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
        double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
        at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle));
        g.transform(at);

        // Draw horizontal arrow starting in (0, 0)
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, len, 0);
        //  g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillPolygon(new int[] {len, len-5, len-5, len}, new int[] {0, -5, 5, 0}, 4);
    }


}


}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided no sizing hints for the scroll pane to determine how big the component should be and thereby determine if it needs to be scrolled.

Start by overriding `MyPannel`'s `getPreferredSize` method and return a value which best represents the size you would like the component to be.

This is best calculated ahead of time if possible

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: You need to tell the scroll pane what size you would like you component to be, it's default size is `0x0`.  Unless you provide a sizing hint yourself, the scroll pane has no idea what size you component should be...

Comment: Yes, you should override the `getPreferredSize` method of your `MyPannel` class, just like you've overridden the `paintComponent` method, which by the way, you should be calling `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting

Comment: Thank you, I added the following code, but I still do not have any scroll bar option. I found some other questions like this, but when I read them, I didn't understand how should I implement this methods :( : @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(1900, 900);
  }

Comment: It would be better to calculate the size rather than guess it

Comment: I tried the code on this page : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AsimpleJScrollPanedemonstration.htm but this one also didn't work, Am I missing something? In addition, I don't know the size of my tree exactly, I can just guess some numbers based on what I see right now

Comment: Based on the fact that you can layout out the tree, you must have a good idea of how high and wide it will be when painted...

Comment: It's a branch and cut process, I am solving a problem by a heuristic approach and I have no Idea about how big a tree could be :) If I could guess the size, I didn't need to use a heuristic approach ;) By the way, I still don't get it, why scroll bar is not showing on my User Interface!!!

Comment: Your panel is to small

Comment: I found it, I reduced the size of the frame, and I can see it now, Thank you so much:)